# Selecting with Regex using the last pattern before the desired capture group not the first

Tags: regex

I have a pattern I want to capture from a string link this:

`**THIS NO** **THIS NO** **THIS NO** **I SAID YES** **THIS NO**`

Where I want to capture the text `I SAID YES`. Since all I have to work with are `**` and `YES` I tried a Regex but it returns the match all the way from the first `**` not the one right before my pattern, see the Regex101 below:

https://regex101.com/r/kUBxQf/1

Comment: Why not just use `/I SAID YES/`? Do you have any constraints? And what certainties do you have? Like do you always want the **fourth** text segment?

Comment: Does your regex flavor support right-to-left searches?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kUBxQf/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you use [`\*\*(?P<Capture>.*?)YES\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/kUBxQf/1) matches `**` and then matches any character non greedy `.*?` until it encounters `YES`. That will match:

`**THIS NO** **THIS NO** **THIS NO** **I SAID YES**`

You could update your regex to match `**` and right after that match not an * `[^*]+` until you encounter `YES`.

[`\*\*(?P<Capture>[^*]+YES)\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/bDGlFD/1)

That will match `I SAID YES`  in group `Capture`

**Explanation**

- `\*\*` Match **
- `(?P<Capture>[^*]+YES)` Capture group and match not * one or more times
- `\*\*` Match **

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
/[A-Z]\s*[A-Z]*(?=\sYES)/
```

This uses a lookahead to capture two uppercase words that directly precede the word `YES`.

Each word is separated by a space, and the above regex ignores the space directly before `YES`.

```js
const string = '**THIS NO** **THIS NO** **THIS NO** **I SAID YES** **THIS NO**';
console.log(string.match(/[A-Z]\s*[A-Z]*(?=\sYES)/));
```

This can also be seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/K3bFEu/1)**.